# exiting a shell script from a c program compiled from the same script

Tags: c, shell, conditional-statements, exit

I've written the following shell script to compile and execute a c program and then to do some other operations.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#FIRST SCRIPT
#
clear
echo "-----STARTING COMPILATION-----"
#echo $1 
name=$1
#echo $name
find . -iname $name -maxdepth 1 -exec cp {} $name \;
new_file="tempwithfile.adb"
cp $name $new_file
cp $name1 $name
echo "compiling"
dir >filelist.txt
gcc writefile.c
run_file="run_file.txt"
echo $name > $run_file
./a.out
echo ""
echo "cleaning"
echo ""
make clean
make -f makefile
```

Can I stop the execution of the shell script if a particular condition is met in the c program? For e.g, if I am searching for a file from the program and i didn't find it, then I don't have to execute the rest of the shell script. Is it possible?

Comment: you can exit the c program at that point with a special exit value and handle this value in the shell script

Comment: Check out 'set -e' - this will cause the script to exit if any command you run exits with a failure code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Manül said, you need to return a value from the main() function in the C code.

Then you can do this in the script:

```
./a.out
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
...
```